# Checking if variable type is nil when using interface

Tags: if-statement, go, null, typechecking

I have this interface for a cache object which is mirroring the `lru` cache from `github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru`:

```
type Cacher interface {
    Add(key, value interface{})
    Get(key interface{}) (value interface{}, ok bool)

}
```

In `main.go` I create the object when some conditions are met otherwise it stays null:

```
import lru "github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru"
...
var cache *lru.ARCCache
if someCondition {
    cache, _ = lru.NewARC(int(cacheSize))
}

... later on
r.Cache = cache
```

Now, in another package , I check if the cache is nil before doing any operations on it:

```
if r.Cache != nil {
    v, found := r.Cache.Get(...)
}
```

This leads to a `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` [error](https://play.golang.org/p/CRpOu3IwuJE) because the type is not nil but the value is.

My question is how to check if `r.Cache` is nil without having to import `github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru` in that package (which makes using the `Cacher` interface pointless): `if r.Cache != (*lru.ARCCache)(nil)`

Comment: The best approach is to avoid assigning an invalid value to r.Cache.  Show the code that sets r.Cache.

Comment: r.Cache just gets the value of `cache` like in the working example: https://play.golang.org/p/CRpOu3IwuJE

Comment: Fix the problem by declaring `cache` as type `Cacher` (`var cache Cacher`) or by adding an if statement around the assignment to `r.Cache` (`if cache != nil { r.Cache = cache }`).

Comment: Just added a full working example at: https://play.golang.org/p/jTsw7Z-h0kx It does not run there due to playground constraints but you can run it locally.

Comment: declaring it to type Cacher worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid checking for nil concrete value in interface because a nil value may be a valid implementation of the interface.  Here's a somewhat contrived example of where nil is valid:

```
type exampleCacher struct { }

func (c *exampleCacher) Get(key interface{}) (value interface{}, ok bool) }
   if c == nil {
      return nil, false
   }
   ...
}
```

A better fix to the problem is to ensure that the code only assigns valid values to `r.Cache`.

The code in the question always sets `r.Cache` to a non-nil value because the code assigns a concrete type to `r.Cache`.  See the [FAQ entry on nil error](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) for an explanation.

Fix the problem by declaring `cache` as a `Cacher`.

```
var cache Cacher
```

As I mention in my comment above, another fix is:

```
if cache != nil { 
   r.Cache = cache 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that `(*lru.ARCCache)(nil) != Cacher(nil)`.

So just don't assign `(*lru.ARCCache)(nil)` to `r.Cache`.

Here is the fix:

```golang
if cache != nil {
    r.Cache = cache
}
```